# Is it better to use Uri.Absolute or the original string after Uri.TryCreate code execution?

Tags: c#, .net, uri

In the code `Uri.TryCreate(link, UriKind.Absolute, out testurl)` the link is tested if valid and gives a Uri object for it. Should I then use original `string link` or `string testurl.AbsoluteUri` ? because both seem to have same string value after code execution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use any. But the Uri object can give you more details about the url like Host, Scheme etc.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no difference, it doesn't matter. Basically, you are just using the `TryCreate` to validate your URL, so using the original string should be just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You should check for the result of `TryCreate` and use the resulting object if successful, otherwise fail gracefully; if it's purely for validation and the input and output are equivalent (if 'correct') then this is a non-issue.